# How to make collapsible checkboxes with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, collapsable

I want to group certain checkboxes and make them collapsible as well as select/unselect all.

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
  <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="land" class="layers" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="land">Land Parcels</label> 
  <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="road" class="layers" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="road">Roads</label> 
  <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="rail"  class="layers" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="rail">Railroads</label> 
input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="lake"  class="layers" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="lake">Lakes</label>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="points" class="layers"/>
  <label for="points">AMIS Points</label>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="education" id="education" class="layers"/>
  <label for="education">Education</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="childcare" class="layers"/>
    <label for="childcare">Child Care</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="highschool" class="layers"/>
    <label for="highschool">High School</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="stormpipes" class="layers"/>
  <label for="stormpipes">Storm Pipes</label>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fixContentHeight();
    $('.layers').click(changeLayers);
});

function changeLayers () {
    var checked = [];
    $('.layers').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            checked.push($(this).attr('value'));
        }
    });
    mainLayer.params.LAYERS = checked.join(",");
    mainLayer.redraw();
}

$('#education').click(function() {
    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#education').is(':checked'));
});
```

Trying to make child care and high school collapisble within the education checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an unordered list with `data-role="listview"`, add `data-role="collapsible"` to the `li` elements, and nest another unordered list with each checkbox inside the inner list's `li`

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title of collapsible row</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="land" class="layers" checked="checked"/>
                <label for="land">Land Parcels</label> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="layers" id="road" class="layers" checked="checked"/>
                <label for="road">Roads</label> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The margins and paddings will look a bit weird, but you can just tweak the css to fix that